# Facebook thinks my og:image is too small

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

So I'm trying to get the og:image tag working properly on my site (www.listingtrends.com). FB's object debugger tells me that the image isn't big enough, but if you go to the actual image it's seeing (http://www.listingtrends.com/Images/TrendsLogo_Facebook.png), it's 230x200. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Try using an image greater than 600 x 315px (or Use a 200X230px image) because your image width is greater than its height by 30px which makes no sense, then use the debug tool to see the new results

Comment: Why does 230x200 'make no sense'? o_O

Answer (score 1):

Looks like that error showing up is an error in itself, if you look at the [Graph URL](https://graph.facebook.com/499166736843117) for your site it's clearly using the image you supplied:

```
   "title": "ListingTrends.com",
   "image": [
      {
         "url": "http://www.ListingTrends.com/Images/TrendsLogo_Facebook.png",
         "width": 230,
         "height": 200
      }
   ],
   "site_name": "Listing Trends",
```

Even though the debugger's warning isn't actually effecting the data, I'd recommend reporting this as a bug on [the FB dev bug tracker](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/).

Edit: Actually looks like [this is already a reported bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/483025408453290) and they've just marked it as low priority.

Comment: Well then that brings up another question - when I try to use that URL in a status update on FB, it doesn't show that image as one of the potential ones to use, it just grabs the other images on the page. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `og:type="website"` only does special-casing for "From [website name]" on OG entries. What you seem to want to do is type `article` which is used for individual articles on websites with their own unique title and picture.

Comment: The site doesn't have articles, I'm just wanting the same image to be used for any page...

Comment: og:type=website is the default if nothing is specified